# Android: Location Service query

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

I currently have a Location Service that starts on app launch. My onCreate method is as follows:-

```
public void onCreate() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
    // Get a location manager from the system services
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // if GPS is not enabled. Show alert to user.
    if ( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        showEnableLocationsDialog();
    }

    // Get the location provider that best matches the criteria
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    if (bestProvider != null) {
        // Get the user's last known location
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

        MyApp myApp = (MyApp) getApplicationContext();
        myApp.setLocation(location);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(bestProvider)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```

When the GPS is not enabled, i display a dialog prompting the user to enable GPS. My question is, if the user does choose to go to the Settings page to enable GPS, will the remaining flow of getBestProvider() and requestLocationUpdates() be affected when the user launches the app again since the service is already "running" in the background? (just a guess because i am new to Android development as a whole).

the full code of my class is below:-

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
    // Get a location manager from the system services
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // if GPS is not enabled. Show alert to user.
    if ( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        showEnableLocationsDialog();
    }

    // Get the location provider that best matches the criteria
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    if (bestProvider != null) {
        // Get the user's last known location
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        MyApp myApp = (MyApp) getApplicationContext();
        myApp.setLocation(location);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(bestProvider)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {        
    // if a newer location is available, check if its better than current available one
    MyApp myApp = (MyApp) getApplicationContext();
    Location location = myApp.getLocation();
    boolean isBetterLocation = isBetterLocation(location, newLocation);
    if(isBetterLocation) {
        location = newLocation;
    }
}

public static Location getBestLocation(LocationManager locationManager) {

    Location location_gps = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Location location_network = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    // If both are available, get the most recent
    if(location_gps!=null && location_network !=null) {
        return (location_gps.getTime() > location_network.getTime())?location_gps:location_network;
    }
    else if(location_gps==null && location_network ==null){
        return null;
    }
    else
        return (location_gps==null)?location_network:location_gps;

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String s){}
public void onProviderDisabled(String s){}
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b){}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {       
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

private void showEnableLocationsDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myAlertDialog.setTitle("No location services enabled");
    myAlertDialog.setMessage("To find your location, please enable at least one service in the Settings");
    myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // show settings screen
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);
        }}
            );
    myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Skip", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {       
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // do something when the Cancel button is clicked
        }}
            );
    myAlertDialog.show();
}

private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;

/** Determines whether one Location reading is better than the current Location fix
 * @param location  The new Location that you want to evaluate
 * @param currentBestLocation  The current Location fix, to which you want to compare the new one
 */
protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true;
        // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/** Checks whether two providers are the same */
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
        return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}
}
```

Also, I read about how it is a not a good idea to be asking for location updates all the time too and should instead use an AlarmManager. any advice about this too?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it might be worth it to stop the service when `onPause` is executed and start the service `onResume`. This way your service isn't consuming battery and resources when not in use.